# Items are not removing from the recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am building a function in my android app in which user will match two items together
and if both items match to each other a correct icon will display to the item where u clicked to match,and if ur match was wrong then it show u the wrong icon.
There is condition when the match is correct then the both correct items are removed i try various ways to removed but they are not seems perfect.

The matching are based on the languages its a langauge translation app suppose u try to translate the How are u(engilsh) ->to ->Comment vas-tu(french) in that case if those count values are match that mean they are belong to each other so its right

> The value of count I provided from the activity where i adding values to the matchdataholder,By the loop count variable saved the ist lang (english text) at count 1 and 2nd language(french) to count 1 as well but with differnt index

> Activity Class

```
package com.blablacards.activity

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.blablacards.R
import com.blablacards.adapter.MatchAdapter
import com.blablacards.app.retrofit.ApiCall
import com.blablacards.model.FavListItem
import com.blablacards.model.MatchDataHolder
import com.blablacards.model.MatchList
import com.blablacards.model.ResponseFavList
import com.blablacards.utils.AppPref
import com.blablacards.utils.Constants
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_match.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class MatchActivity : BaseActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    var matchDataHolder: ArrayList<MatchDataHolder>? = ArrayList<MatchDataHolder>()
    var favWordList = ArrayList<FavListItem>()
    var matchList = ArrayList<MatchList>()
    var categoryId: Int? = null
    var categoryName: String? = null

    lateinit var matchAdapter: MatchAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_match)

        img_back.setOnClickListener(this)

        getBundleData()

        tv_header.text = categoryName

        favWordList.clear()
        calFavCategoryListApi("DESC")
        // setAdapter()

    }

    private fun setAdapter(favWordList: ArrayList<MatchDataHolder>) {
        Toast.makeText(this@MatchActivity, "Adapter called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        matchAdapter = MatchAdapter(
            this@MatchActivity,
            favWordList
        )
        println("FAV LIST SIZE ->" + favWordList.size)
        rv_match.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@MatchActivity, 2)
        rv_match.adapter = matchAdapter
    }

    private fun getBundleData() {
        val extras = intent.extras
        if (extras != null) {
            categoryId = extras.getInt("CategoryId")
            categoryName = extras.getString("CategoryName")
            println("!!!categoryId = ${categoryId}")
        }
    }

    private fun calFavCategoryListApi(sortBy: String) {
        ApiCall.initApiCall(Constants.BASE_URL).getFavcategoryList(
            "Bearer" + AppPref.getValue(AppPref.TOKEN, ""),
            AppPref.getValue(AppPref.LOGIN_ID, "")!!, categoryId.toString(), "", "", sortBy
        ).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseFavList> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResponseFavList>,
                response: Response<ResponseFavList>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    if (response.body()!!.status!!) {
                        favWordList.addAll(response.body()!!.data!!)
                        //
                        for (i in 0 until favWordList.size) {
                            matchDataHolder!!.add(MatchDataHolder(favWordList[i].sended_text.toString(),i))
                            matchDataHolder!!.add(MatchDataHolder(favWordList[i].return_text.toString(),i))

                        }
                        for(i in 0 until matchDataHolder!!.size){
                         println("DATA HOLDER ->"+ matchDataHolder!![i].text)
                            println("DATA HOLDER  Count->"+ matchDataHolder!![i].count)
                        }
                        //
                        setAdapter(matchDataHolder!!)

                    } else {
                        showSnackBar(response.message())
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseFavList>, t: Throwable) {
                println("!!!t.message = ${t.message}")
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when (v!!.id) {
            R.id.img_back -> {
                onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Adapter Class

```
package com.blablacards.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Handler

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.blablacards.R
import com.blablacards.model.MatchDataHolder
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.row_match.view.*

class MatchAdapter(
    var context: Context,
    var favWordList: ArrayList<MatchDataHolder>,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    var index1 = -1
    var index2 = -1
    var enabledFlag = false
    var oldPos = -1
    var newPos = -1
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.row_match, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as MatchAdapter.ViewHolder).bind(position)

        holder.itemView.rl_match.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.white))
        holder.itemView.tv_match.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        holder.itemView.rl_match.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            if (!enabledFlag) {
                println(enabledFlag)
                println("IF block")
                it.rl_match.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.orange_light3))
                holder.itemView.tv_match.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                oldPos = favWordList[position].count
                println("OLD POS ->" + oldPos)
                index1 = position
                println("index 1 = " + index1)
                enabledFlag = true
            } else {

                // show the correct and wrong //
                println("ELSE BLOCK")
                enabledFlag = false
                newPos = favWordList[position].count
                println("NEW POS ->" + newPos)
                index2 = position
                println("index 2 = " + index2)
                showCorrectOrFalse(holder.itemView, favWordList[position].count)

            }
        })

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return favWordList.size
    }
    
    private fun timeHandler(itemView: View, status: String, position: Int) {
        Handler().postDelayed({
            if (status == "right") {
                println("inside right")
                itemView.tv_match.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                itemView.rl_match.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                itemView.img_right_or_wrong.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
//                favWordList.drop(index1)
//                favWordList.drop(index2)
/// THE PROBLEM IS HERE CUZ I'm not able to perfectly removed the item//
                favWordList.remove(MatchDataHolder(favWordList[index1].text,newPos))
                favWordList.remove(MatchDataHolder(favWordList[index2].text,oldPos))
                notifyItemRemoved(index1)
                notifyItemRemoved(index2)
                notifyItemRangeChanged(index1,favWordList.size)
                notifyItemRangeChanged(index2,favWordList.size)
                notifyDataSetChanged()

            }
            if (status == "wrong") {
                println("Inside wrong")
                itemView.tv_match.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                itemView.rl_match.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.white))
                itemView.img_right_or_wrong.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }, 2000)
    }

    private fun showCorrectOrFalse(itemView: View, position: Int) {
        println("SHOW CORRECT CALLED")
        //call handler after click //
        println("OLD POS " + oldPos + " New POS " + newPos)
        if (oldPos == newPos) {
            itemView.img_right_or_wrong.setImageDrawable(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.right_game))
            Toast.makeText(context, "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            timeHandler(itemView, "right", position)
        } else {
            itemView.img_right_or_wrong.setImageDrawable(context.resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.wrong_game))
            timeHandler(itemView, "wrong", position)
        }
    }

    internal inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun bind(position: Int) {
            itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_match).text =
                favWordList[position].text

        }
    }
}
```

> A model class for hold the data of item

```
class MatchDataHolder(text:String,num:Int) {
    var count = num
    var text =text
}
```

Comment: since i need to remove both location at the same time  ->>  favwordList.removeAt(index1)   and favwordList.removeAt(index2)  showing the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
favWordList.remove(MatchDataHolder(favWordList[index1].text,newPos))
```

you remove a new `MatchDataHolder` which is not exist in `favWordList`

you can try this:

```
 favWordList.removeAt(index1)
```

Comment: thanks @panhe i try this before but forget to mention int the question, favwordList.removeAt(index1) is showing error sometimes it will show arrayindexoutbound and sometimes it will remove postion but one of the are came back inside the recycler view (i can't understand why index is out of bound even if the location is exist)

Comment: maybe like an example： array = [0,1,2] after removeAt[1]  array = [0,2] ,    if you call removeAt[2] again, you get  arrayindexoutbound

Comment: yes i think ur right so what to do in that case if i wanna remove both the selected pos like array[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and i removed remove[0,1](which is a match) so how to mange rest of position after that ? #i deeply appriciate your time

Comment: There are many ways to do this,  you can try like this  
            val item1 =  favWordList.get[index1]
            val item2 =  favWordList.get[index2]
            favWordList.remove(item1)
            favWordList.remove(item2)

Comment: thanks u soo much #panhe i really thankfull to u on this one u saved my many hours dude #kudos to u